# Orbeon : how to display username on page banner using epilogue?

Tags: orbeon

I'm using form authentication on tomcat with orbeon. I can display user credentials on a specific page (I adapted the java-authentication sample). I also implemented a logout link on all pages using a custom theme (it's a simple href to /authentication/logout).

I wonder if there is a simple way to display something like "You are logged as USERNAME (ROLE)" on the page banner using my custom theme ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this in the [theme](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/page-flow-epilogue#TOC-Theming), which is in XSLT:

1. Adding a link to the logout page should be straightforward.
2. To show the username of the current user, from XForms, you can call [`xxf:get-remote-user()`](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-xpath-functions#TOC-xxforms%3aget-remote-user-). But the theme XSLT runs after XForms processing, so you can't use XForms there. Instead, you would need to call Java code, that you [call from XSLT](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.1/extensibility/functions.html): `org.orbeon.oxf.util.NetUtils.getExternalContext().getRequest().getRemoteUser()`.
3. For the role, the servlet API doesn't allow you to get the user's roles; you can only check if the user has a specific role with `isUserInRole()`, which you would call similarly to the `getRemoteUser()` of point 2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't knew I can call java methods. That will be very useful.

Comment: BTW, I have another question about the theme : I implemented a "left side selector menu" in my pages, with items dynamically generated from a xquery request. I would like to "factorize" those menus in the theme. How can I do that ? Do I have to forward data to the epilogue ? Can I make a xquery request from within the theme ? The latter would be my favorite, but don't know if it's possible.

Comment: @cbosson Yes, indeed, calling Java code from XSLT came come in handy. And BTW, this is a capability of Saxon, which Orbeon Forms is using. The syntax gets a bit heavy if you need to do a lot of calls, but it works well for the occasional Java call.

Comment: @cbosson If you're using a 4.0 milestone build, you can call a pipeline from XSLT with `p:call-xpl()`, with `p` prefix `xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"`. Then in your pipeline, you can implement all the logic you want, including running the `oxf:xforms-submission` processor to make a request to eXist. For more on `call-xpl()`, see http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-xpath-functions#TOC-xxforms:call-xpl-

Comment: Still using 3.9, and I would like to avoid xxforms extensions (for now). Do you see another way of doing that ? Maybe I can also use a java call to exist ?

Comment: @cbosson OK, got it. Like you say, you could call Java code which does the call to eXist, or change the `epilogue-servlet.xpl` https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/config/epilogue-servlet.xpl to run the `oxf:xforms-submission` processor, which you use to call the eXist REST API, before it runs the theme, and feed the output as another input to the theme.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your inputs. Very appreciated !